# How to use a ConvexHull as RegionFunction?

Tags: plotting, computational-geometry

I have a set of data supported over a region in 2D. I want to use RegionPlot and ContourPlot on interpolations of my data, but want to restrict the Plots to the region over which my data is supported.

[Paste](http://pastebin.com/VVsV012p) of the supports of my data.

I easily find the region with ConvexHull from the ComputationalGeometry package:

> Graphics[Polygon[l2[[ConvexHull[l2]]]]]

[image]

Now I want to turn the information into something I can use as RegionFunction for the ContourPlots and as restrictions in RegionPlot.

Can you show me a way?

Comment: Thank you, I agree, it is almost a duplicate. Only new thing here is the use as RegionFunction, but the efficiency of the anwers provided at your link should allow that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Version 10 (now available publicly through the Programming Cloud) supports an alternative way for restricting functions to a certain region.  This method can be directly used with `Polygon` objects, as well as any other [geometrical region](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/GeometricComputation.html).

Here's an example:

```
poly=Polygon[{{1, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]}, {-1, 0}}]

ContourPlot[x^2+y^2, {x,y} ∈ poly]
```

[image]

There's also new functionality [for finding convex hulls](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConvexHullMesh.html), and the resulting object is a region, so it can be used in `ContourPlot` as the function domain:

```
points = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {6, 2}]

ContourPlot[x^2+y^2, {x,y} ∈ ConvexHullMesh[points]]
```

[image]

*Warning:* using this syntax will cause Mathematica to use a different sampling algorithm during plotting, as evidenced by the mesh that gets generated:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I just found a solution in a comment by J.M.

He offers the function

```
inPolyQ[pt_?VectorQ, poly_?MatrixQ] := 
Chop[Total[VectorAngle @@@ Partition[(# - pt) & /@ poly, 2, 1, 
{1, 1 - 2 Boole[TrueQ[First[poly] == Last[poly]]]}]] - 2 π] == 0
```

to do exactly what I need to be done.

If l2 is the List of the supports of my data, I can use

```
pol = l2[[ConvexHull[l2]]];
inPol = inPolyQ2[#, pol] &;
```

to have a constraint for RegionPlot:

```
RegionPlot[otherStuff && inPol[{x, y}], {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 60}]
```

and to have a RegionFunction

```
ContourPlot[int[x, y], {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 60}, RegionFunction -> (inPol[#1, #2] &)]
```

Edit: There even is the built-in function Graphics`Mesh`InPolygonQ[poly, point] that checks if "point" is in the polygon "poly".